# Node.js - Http get will not display data from MongoDb query in Postman or browser

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a node.js backend project that uses a MongoDb database. After I query the database and received the data it will not display the data in my browser using res.send(). I also tried res.json(). However, the data does display on my console,but just will not display in postman or my browser. Is the query data from mongoDB not json or an array? I did a little reading and it states it's a cursor pointing to the data. Can this data not be converted to display in a broswer?

[mycode as well as console and browser display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tATF3.png)

```
ProductRouter.js
```

router.get('/', (req, res) => {

const products =  allProducts.plantProducts();

setTimeout(() => {

```
    if (products === "400") {

        res.status("400").send("Error querying database");

    }else{

      console.log(products);

      res.status("200").send(products);

    }
```

}, 1000);

```
ProductController.js
```

async function plantProducts(){

try {

```
const products = await getProducts();

return products;
```

} catch(err) {

```
let code = "400";

return code; 

//res.status('400').send(err.message);
```

}

}

plantProducts();

//Search mongodb for all products.

function getProducts() {

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const products = Product

    .find()

    resolve(products);

});
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO - please edit your question and include the code instead of posting images.

Comment: productRoutes.js – Calls planProducts method in ProductController.js file:
//get All Plant Products.
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const products =  allProducts.plantProducts();
  setTimeout(() => {
        if (products === "400") {
            res.status("400").send("Error querying database");
        }else{
          console.log(products);
          res.status("200").send(products);
        }
  }, 1000);

Comment: I added the full code that handles the query. In my ProductRoute.js file I called the PlantProducts function in the ProductController.js file. This if the async function that calls the getProducts function and wait's it promise.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `products` yields a promise which express' `res.json` will not automatically await and convert to a json-response. You need await the promise and then send the response. Something like:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    const products = await allProducts.plantProducts();
    res.json(products);
});
```

Comment: I'm doing that in the function that does the query. The code in the screenshot is what is returned when I call the function. Below is the actual function that does the query and it has an await on it. Again it promise is resolved as it prints the data to the console, just not the browser.

Comment: async function plantProducts(){
  try {
    const products = await getProducts();
    return products;
  } catch(err) {
    let code = "400";
    return code; 
    //res.status('400').send(err.message);
  }   
}
plantProducts();

Comment: Are you saying both the calling function and function being called both need await? I currently call the function and the function being called is an async function that calls another function with the promise. This promise is returned to the calling async function and resolved. Last this resolved function returns the data back to the original calling function.

Comment: Here's the full code for querying the MongoDB database to get products from the products collection:

Comment: Happy to hear that.Please mark the answer as accepted or post your own answer with your solution and accept that one.